# Extract href text from website

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

How Can I extract href text from website?

```
<div class="ba by"><a href="http://somewebaddress.com">**I want this text!**</a></div>
```

I try some  solution, but doesn't work.

```
Dim myMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim myRegex As New Regex("<div.*?class=""ba by"".*?>.*</div>", RegexOptions.Singleline)
    Dim wc As New WebClient
    Dim html As String = wc.DownloadString("http://somewebaddress.com")
    TextBox1.Text = html
    myMatches = myRegex.Matches(html)
    MsgBox(html)
            Dim successfulMatch As Match
    For Each successfulMatch In myMatches
        MsgBox(successfulMatch.Groups(1).ToString)
    Next
```

**or**

```
Dim divs = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("div")
        For Each d As HtmlElement In divs
            If d.GetAttribute("class") = "ba by" Then
                TextBox1.Text = d.InnerText
            End If
        Next
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of ...

```
Dim divs = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("div")
```

Try...

```
Dim anchors = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("a")
```

That should get you a list of all the "